# Postman - How to get the value from a JSON response for the last occurrence of the required attributes

Tags: json, postman

I am new to JSON and Postman. I believe I'm trying to do something very simple.

I have created a GET request which will get a JSON response like the one below.

In the example below I want to get the value of the last "IsArchived" attribute (the one just before the "Version"); Or the one that does not belong to a FieldGroup.

How can I do it? (although maybe it will be answered by an answer to my other question)  Thanks in advance

```
{
    "Id": 1328,
    "Name": "AAA Test",
    "Owner": {
        "Id": 208,
        "Name": "The Boss"
    },
    "FieldGroups": [
        {
            "Id": "c81376f0-6ac3-4028-8d61-76a0f815dbf8",
            "Name": "General",
            "FieldDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "DisplayName": "Product Name",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "DisplayName": "Short Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 33,
                    "DisplayName": "Long Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "5ed8746b-0fa8-4022-8216-ad3af17db91f",
            "Name": "Somethingelse",
            "FieldDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Id": 123,
                     "DisplayName": "Attribution",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 1584,
                    "DisplayName": "FC1",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 623,
                    "DisplayName": "Sizes",
                    "IsArchived": false,
                    "Owner": {
                        "Id": 208,
                        "Name": "The Boss"
                    },
                    "Unit": "",
                    "Options": [
                        {
                            "Id": 1,
                            "Value": "XS"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 2,
                            "Value": "S"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 3,
                            "Value": "M"
                        },
                    ]
                }
             ]
        }
    ],
    },
    "IsArchived": false
    "Version": 1
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be rather easy because your `IsArchived` attribute is on the top level of the JSON response, so it will not happen that another `IsArchived` value is used unless you somehow loop through your `FieldGroups` array like in your other question.

```
// Convert the response body to a JSON object
var jsonData = pm.response.json()

// Create a variable and assign the value of IsArchived to it
var isArchived = jsonData.IsArchived;

// OR create a Postman environment variable and assign the value of IsArchived to it
pm.environment.set("isArchived", jsonData.IsArchived);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the JSON you're dealing with is not valid. You can always check your JSON validity with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Here is the valid JSON:

```
{
    "Id": 1328,
    "Name": "AAA Test",
    "Owner": {
        "Id": 208,
        "Name": "The Boss"
    },
    "FieldGroups": [{
            "Id": "c81376f0-6ac3-4028-8d61-76a0f815dbf8",
            "Name": "General",
            "FieldDefinitions": [{
                    "Id": 1,
                    "DisplayName": "Product Name",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "DisplayName": "Short Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 33,
                    "DisplayName": "Long Description",
                    "IsArchived": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "5ed8746b-0fa8-4022-8216-ad3af17db91f",
            "Name": "Somethingelse",
            "FieldDefinitions": [{
                    "Id": 123,
                    "DisplayName": "Attribution",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 1584,
                    "DisplayName": "FC1",
                    "IsArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "Id": 623,
                    "DisplayName": "Sizes",
                    "IsArchived": false,
                    "Owner": {
                        "Id": 208,
                        "Name": "The Boss"
                    },
                    "Unit": "",
                    "Options": [{
                            "Id": 1,
                            "Value": "XS"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 2,
                            "Value": "S"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 3,
                            "Value": "M"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "IsArchived": false,
    "Version": 1
}
```

Now I assume that you want to get attribute in Postman test, you can achieve as here:

```
var responseData = pm.response.json();
var isArchived = responseData.isArchived;
```

Comment: Thanks Div. Your answer works, just need to use ".IsArchived" instead of ".isArchived".

Comment: btw, why my json is not valid? I do not see the difference between yours and mine.

Comment: @KVN: copy your JSON, goto https://jsonlint.com/ paste there and click on validate button, they will tell you what's wrong

Comment: @KVN You had some `,` where they were not needed: after the last object in your arrays.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks Div!

Comment: @Div do you know, by any chances, the answer to my other question (on the Count of All "IsArchived" in the response?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463615/postman-how-to-get-a-count-from-a-json-response-for-a-specific-attributes